# Top Comments,Top Users,Top Users and Comments mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `comments` | `votes`.

```
The `votes` structure is:
[`id` | `user_id` | `comment_id`  | `rating`]
```

and the comments has the comment_id as the primary.
Now I want get the top comments according to the sum of rating.

**[rating is 0 or 1]**

and I want to get the top users too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the top 10 comments change the limit for more or less.
Obviously replace the * with the columns you want returned from comments

```
select *
from comments x
join (select comment_id, sum(rating)
      from votes 
      group by comment_id
      order by sum(rating) desc
      limit 10 ) z on x.comment_id = z.comment_id
```

users will be done in the same way just change the comment_id from the user_id and join to you

Comment: in users , its give me the same user twice

Comment: It shouldnt return the same user_id twice as the group by will remove duplicates. Check the user_id of the users returned it could be that the user has been entered twice. If it hasnt can you post the sql you used for the users.